# Does Mono for Android Support "dynamic" Keyword & ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, dynamic, xamarin.android, expandoobject

I want to use dynamic ExpandoObjects for a project I'm working on, but it doesn't compile with what I think is the correct configuration.

From what I can see Mono supports the dynamic keyword and ExpandoObject, so I am assuming it is either a configuration issue or somehow it's not possible in Mono for Android.

When I try to use it though, I get the following error messages in Visual Studio 2010:

> Error  3   One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll? D:\HMI\ExpandoTest\ExpandoTest\Activity1.cs 34  17  ExpandoTest
>
> Error  1   Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported  ExpandoTest

Here is the simple test code:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ExpandoTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "ExpandoTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Test the expando stuff
            TestExpando();
        }

        private void TestExpando()
        {
            dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
            int x = 10;
            obj.x = x;    // This line and the next one generate compiler errors
            obj["X"] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: I tried compiling under MonoDevelop 3.0 and got the same errors.  Not sure if it's related, but I have Unity installed too, which installs another version of MonoDevelop.  The two don't seem to interfere with each other in any other way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler error message states, you need to add a reference to the Microsoft.CSharp assembly in order to use the dynamic keyword:

[image: Add reference to Microsoft.CSharp]

Comment: Thanks Greg, that fixed it!  I've been in embedded systems land for most of my career and more recently in Xcode.  I wasn't familiar with the "Add Reference" concept in VS2010.  One odd thing though is that my Add Reference dialog looks nothing like yours for some reason.

Comment: No problem! The different Add Reference dialog is due to having this extension installed: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef